# ICS in windows server 2003

Tags: windows

I have a problem, I use windows server 2003 r2, have 2 Internet Card
Properties (internet card)> Advanced tab> just "Windows Firewall" display but ICS is not display

Help me, i need ICS

Answer (score 1):

Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) is for consumer/client systems, not for Windows Server OS.  You need to use the Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) features in Windows Server.  Please refer to this Microsoft KB article for detailed information on setting up RRASS for your version of Windows: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816581

It sounds like you will only need to worry about the Routing and can skip the parts about  the VPN (PPTP) Remote Access. But Routing with NAT is the equivalent of ICS.

There might be some limitation on the types of network interfaces that are supported in Windows 2003 and 2003R2.  Specifically I remember there were challenges in setting up wireless (WiFi/GSM/3G) type NICs.

Good luck.

Comment: i trying NAT between network and internet but IP address Internet card not changes because Mail server ( MDeamon ) running. When i enable Lan card and NAT config then Client connect to server not found my domain and just connect to internet with DNS 8.8.8.8
....i try config ISA 2004 and ISA give to me IP address 169.254.0.0 - 169.254.255.255 and Lan card config ip address is 169.254.0.1, CLient ip address 169.254.0.2 and client connect to Lan card but not connecting to internet, i think DNS wrong but i changes, changes changes,...but it not connecting to internet, just ping to Lan card - it ok